# Difference between edge policy and WAF policy

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am new user to oracle cloud infrastructure. I am trying to use WAF policy on my web application. There are edge and waf policy that seem to be the same.

So I wonder the difference of that two policy? Do I need to add both[edge,WAF] policy or either one?

Answer (score 3):

LB-WAF it's OCI new version for the WAF that works as a Policy attached to a load balancer, the main difference is that the WAF service and the Load Balancer Service works side by side instead of separately as the previous version of the WAF,
check some of the main differences.

Web Application Firewall is OCI standard suite of features and countermeasures designed to help protect and enhance your Web Application against Layer 7 threats.
Web Application Firewall has two versions, Edge WAF (WAF v1) and Regional WAF (WAF v2/LB WAF), each serving a different purpose.

The main difference between them is that Regional WAF is specifically attached to an OCI Load Balancer and acts more so as an expansion to the LB providing additional security functionality and is recommended for customers with a strong regional presence, whereas Edge WAF (The version you are currently using) is used by customers that want to accommodate their already established infrastructure with additional security features.
WAF Rules in Regional WAF work differently compared to Edge WAF Regional WAF allows the use of optional condition functions, which as the name implies allows you to set particular conditions for a WAF rule to match, for example, “Country/Region in list” when if matched results in a pre-set action, "allow", "allow but log", or "return a specified HTTP response".

Other key differences

- Both services have logging, for Regional WAF it has to be enabled manually.
- Changes in Regional WAF propagate significantly faster due to them taking place in a Load Balancer compared to multiple servers across the world.
- While Regional WAF Allows for rule filtering and similar functionality can be achieved with Edge WAF via the OCI CLI.
- Regional WAF does not currently offer the "Bot Management" suite of countermeasures, however, the feature set is on the roadmap.
- Regional WAF has "Advanced IP Rate Limiting", an improved version of "IP Rate Limiting" available in Edge WAF and configurable via CLI.
- Caching Rules are not available in Regional WAF

Comment: Question and answers are a bit old, but just to clarify what @texaspark said:

WAF policy = regional solution
Edge policy = global solution